# How to remove zoom control from the Mapbox Map?

Tags: javascript, html, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I have a quick question about how you can remove the zoom control from the MapBox Map.

Below is the current code I have.

I have placed "zoomControl: false" inside the styleLayer section, but it doesn't seem to work...

Can someone help me solve this issue?

```html
<script>
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGhsZWUxMTIyIiwiYSI6ImNpeWdyd2tycDAzZTUzMm12eDcybjJocTgifQ.r1njnGgI95MNlwVBTm1slw';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map') 
        .setView([14.43232, 14.4165], 3);

    // Use styleLayer to add a Mapbox style created in Mapbox Studio
          L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/thlee1122/ciyhpbj15003d2sluqt6ylrqa', {zoomControl: false}).addTo(map);

    map.dragging.disable();
    map.touchZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

zoomControl is an option of L.mapbox

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', { zoomControl: false })
```

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-mapbox-map/

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-option

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work...
I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error in the console.

When I click on that error, it takes me to "tile_layer.js" file, which I did not create. I think it comes with leaflet or mapbox package.

It says below is the part where I am getting error:
_setTileJSON: function(json) {
        util.strict(json, 'object');

        this.options.format = this.options.format ||
            json.tiles[0].match(formatPattern)[1];

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: sorry, I missed the 2nd arg before the options (I'm not too sure what you have to put in your case)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using styleLayer to add a Mapbox style created in Mapbox Studio you have to add "**null**" to the call before passing options.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', null, { zoomControl:false });

L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/xxxxx').addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer!